# Trouble installing python VirtualEnv in windows 10 using powershell

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

I am trying to install a virtualenv in windows 10 using a step process I found on some website. The steps are as follows, but only care about 1-4 for now:

1. Run Windows Power Shell as Administrator
2. pip install virtualenv
3. pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
4. mkvirtualenv ‘C:\Users\username\Documents\Virtualenv’
5. cd Test
6. Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned | Press Y and Enter
7. Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned | Press Y and Enter
8. .\Scripts\activate
9. deactivate

Steps 1-3 work fine, but when I try step four I get the following response:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> mkvirtualenv 'C:\Users\username\Documents\Virtualenv'
Using base prefix 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32'
New python executable in C:\Users\DANIEL~1\DOCUME~1\VIRTUA~1\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The cd step following right afterwords does not work aswell. I am pretty new to python/programming in general so I might be missing some basic things.

running step 5 gives the following error message:

cd : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Virtualenv' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd Virtualenv
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\system32\Virtualenv:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you replace username before starting step 4?

Comment: Yeah I did. I did read somewhere that their might be an issue if you have spaces in your windows username? is that a possibility? Mine includes a first and last name

Answer (score 0):

1) set virtual environment directory in path variable- `export WORKON_HOME=(directory you need to save envs)`

2) `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh -p $WORKON_HOME`

source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` or which virtualenvwrapper.sh can used to locate virtualenvwrapper.sh file.

It's best to put above two lines in ~/.bashrc to avoid executing the above commands every time you open new shell. That's all you need to create environment using mkvirtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Use Anaconda, is the best way to manage your python packages, in my opinion.